# Xen error: "xl list" complains about libxl

Tags: arch-linux, xen, uefi

After having installed Xen on Arch Linux, I cannot issue any xl commands, getting this error:

```
xc: error: Could not obtain handle on privileged command interface (2 = No such file or directory): Internal error

libxl: error: libxl.c:109:libxl_ctx_alloc: cannot open libxc handle: No such file or directory

cannot init xl context
```

Of dmesg, I see these messages during boot:

```
[    0.000000] efi: EFI_MEMMAP is not enabled.
[    0.000000] esrt: ESRT header is not in the memory map.
[   14.270676] Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)
```

Full dmesg:
http://pastebin.com/uLUVawtZ

Comment: Have you started xen services? It requires `/etc/init.d/xencommons start` and mounting xenfs in `/proc/xen` in my Debian...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to mvault giving me something to try.
I then suddenly noticed that my error message was slightly different from what I've written down here:

```
xc: error: Could not obtain handle on privileged command interface (13 = Permission denied): Internal error
libxl: error: libxl.c:109:libxl_ctx_alloc: cannot open libxc handle: No such file or directory
```

And this one is very easy to solve with

```
$ sudo xl list
```

I must have gotten awfully confused, because on another board I wrote down the latter error, as booting into Xen as well as it's xl error message are very similar to booting into regular Arch Linux and it's xl error message.

Answer (score 3):

[problem]

> xencall: error: Could not obtain handle on privileged command interface: No such file or directory
>
> libxl: error: libxl.c:108:libxl_ctx_alloc: cannot open libxc handle: No such file or directory
>
> cannot init xl context

[solution]

```
sudo /etc/init.d/xencommons start    
sudo /etc/init.d/xendomains start    
sudo /etc/init.d/xen-watchdog start    
sudo /etc/init.d/xendriverdomain start
```

Answer (score 0):

Run into this problem installing from sources (an old version 4.4.1). Despite all the above answers my problem has a different root cause.

Maybe you've installed correctly but not updated your grub2 properly. Some evidences is the `/proc/xen` not mounted. Check your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` for the menuentry with the xen.gz and update the `/etc/default/grub` and run the `sudo update-grub` some helpfull command could be:

```
awk '/menuentry/ && /class/ {count++; print count-1"****"$0 }'      /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep -i "Xen"

# update grub with the apropriate index (in my case 3)
sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_DEFAULT=[0-9]/GRUB_DEFAULT=3/' /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub

sudo reboot
```